# How do you make Django search for templates in project root directory?

Tags: python, django, routes

Right now

If I added these setting to settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'project',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

It will search for index.html in

```
where_manage_py_is_at/project/templates/index.html
```

not

```
where_manage_py_is_at/templates/index.html
```

which is very perplexing since

```
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
```

refers to

```
    where_manage_py_is_at/templates/index.html
```

Can someone tell me why is django doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do like this,try

in `manage.py` #at top of file like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

in `settings.py`

```
from manage import BASE_DIR as T_BASE_DIR
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(T_BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```